# Why my view cached is not stable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Before asking my question, i read document [configurigng Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

and i still don't know reason why my view cached is not working stably. In my case, after updating the codes in views, sometimes i don't need restart application server(Thin) and the views is reloaded with the modifications Seen that the controllers and models are not reloaded, so my app crashes ... Strange, this problem is not always there it's not stably. sometimes all is ok.

my config production mode like this:

```
...
# Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true
...
```

From the documentation, i learned that if i set `true` to `config.cache_classes`, i don't need to set `true` to `config.action_view.cache_template_loading` it will follow cache_classes configuring.

I think that cache_classes controls if all classes, modules and views templates will reload for each request. am i right ? any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: On production, with RAILS_ENV=production, it's good to always restart app server. The production is for caching and prealoading to speed-up. How do you 'update' the code on production? If not using any deployment tool check out capistrano http://capistranorb.com/

Comment: my project folder is  a git  repository, every time, i do `git pull` for update. i prefer to do this manuelly.

Comment: why do it manually when you can manully call 'cap deploy' which will deploy, git pull, run migrations, restart et all. check out capistrano if you want to have app server auto restarted